# Android Studio > GridLayout > how to get the position of a cell?

Tags: java, android, android-gridlayout

```
<GridLayout
        android:id="@+id/gridLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/linearLayout"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:onClick="markSquare" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:onClick="markSquare" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_row="1"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:onClick="markSquare" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_row="1"
            android:onClick="markSquare" />

</GridLayout>
```

**Description:**
Each button is inside a cell and points to a method called "markSquare", which looks like this:

```
public void markSquare(View v) {
}
```

How can I get the position of the "v" parameter? (the same position I specified in "layout_row" and "layout_column")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no direct way to get the position of the cell. However you use the view id to get exact view that click.

1: Give the specific ids to the button.i.e button1, button2

2:And check your view clicks id's like:

```
 public void markSquare(View v) {
    switch(v.getId()){
    case R.id.button1:{
    //Do here what you want
    break;
    }

    case R.id.button2:{
    //Do here what you want

    break;
    }

    }
 }
```

Comment: If that's so, then I see no advantage in using GridLayout in my case. I just wanted to create a grid of buttons in order to make something similiar to the Tic-Tac-Toe game. So, instead, I will use a LinearLayout for each row (orientation="horizontal"), since it is simpler.